# ajax call in Rails fails to render a js.haml

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am following Railscast #174 to implement a pagination with ajax. In my account_controller.rb:

```
  def index
    @accounts = Account.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  end
```

I am using haml format in the views, so I have a index.haml file where I have included

```
= will_paginate @accounts
```

Also crated pagination.js file

```
$(function () {
  $('.pagination a').click(function () {
    $.get(this.href, null, null, 'script');
    return false;
  });
});
```

I have verified that the pagination.js code is accessed. In the console I see response code 200 and html returned but the index.js.haml file is not being rendered

```
alert("This is an AJAX request.");
```

The Railscast is using an js.erb extension but I am using haml in the rest of the project, I suspect it can have something to do with that but I cannot figure out what is wrong. Would anybody have an idea?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console log in developer tools?

Comment: no, no errors anywhere, but I can see in the log that the index action is being requested as HTML and not JS: 'Processing by Admin::AccountsController#index as HTML'

Answer (score 0):

You have to use  `event.preventDefault()` in your js code.

Try this:

```
$(function () {
  $('.pagination a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.get(this.href, null, null, 'script');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: how bout event.stopPropagation()

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing it like this,

```
  $('.pagination').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get(this.href, null, null, 'script');
    return false;
  });
```

or maybe binding it to the .container (if you have one, where .container is class inside which your whole content lies)

since your alert() is not being shown, i suspect that although your js is loaded, it doesnot get triggered.

Comment: Unfortunately the entire page gets reloaded this way.

Answer (score 0):

Rails4 uses turbo links which doesn't reloads the whole page. So the 'page ready' js trigger won't be triggered all the time, but in those cases the 'page:change' is triggered.

```
$(document).on("page:change ready", function(){
   $('.pagination a').click(function () {
...
});
```

Comment: Thanks Boti, but again, the alert is not appearing. What concerns me is that in the log I can see 'Processing AccountsController#index as HTML'. I would think that the last argument of the ajax call ('script') should request the page in JS format, but maybe I am wrong?

Comment: Try this and tell me the results:

alert('loaded');
$(document).on("page:change ready", function(){
   alert('page change');
   $('.pagination a').click(function () {
   alert('click');
...
});

Comment: on page load I get 2 alert popups: first says loaded and when dismissed, the other appears that says page change. After I click one of the pagination links, the third popup appears which says 'click'

Comment: Good that means that the js part works perfectly. Now you need to check the server log and see if the result is rendered.

Could you share your view file please?

Comment: Started GET "/admin/accounts?page=2&_=1415026041579" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-03 14:47:28 +0000
Processing by Admin::AccountsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"page"=>"2", "_"=>"1415026041579"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1232  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  ....
  Rendered admin/accounts/_accounts.haml (164.5ms)
  Rendered admin/shared/_content_card.html.haml (168.0ms)
  Rendered admin/accounts/index.haml within layouts/admin (208.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 248ms (Views: 221.0ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)

Comment: It looks like the selected page is loading but the index.js.erb is not being rendered

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this code to the controller:

`respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js {render :layout => false }
end`